# Using sed to match and add new line to config file produces duplicate line

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to build a sed query that matches for CONFIG_BLUE and then add CONFIG_GREEN below it. The query I made works but the result is the same line duplicated twice.

Sed query;

`sed -i -e '/CONFIG_BLUE/a\' -e '# CONFIG_GREEN=y' test.txt`

Example;

```
CONFIG_BLUE=y
CONFIG_GREEN=y
CONFIG_GREEN=y (This shouldn't be here)
```

I am very rusty with regex. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Loop snippet from the script (allows for test1.txt, test2.txt, etc.)
Only using 1 file currently, haven't expanded to more yet.

```
for i in test*.txt
do
  sed -i -e '/CONFIG_BLUE/a\' -e '# CONFIG_GREEN=y' test.txt
done
```

Comment: It's always going to add CONFIG_GREEN after a CONFIG_BLUE. I'm guessing a CONFIG_GREEN already existed when you ran the command?

Comment: @vincent No, CONFIG_GREEN doesn't exist until after I run sed.

Comment: Your command is missing a quote. I also can't reproduce what you claim is happening. It only adds one instance of `'# CONFIG_GREEN=y` which what your command is supposed to do. You can also leave out the `-e` and just use `sed '/CONFIG_BLUE/a CONFIG_GREEN=y' test.txt` and get the result that you want which doesn't include the `# ` according to your question.

Comment: Same. If i run this: `sed -i -e '/CONFIG_BLUE/a\#CONFIG_GREEN=y' test.txt` it works as expected. The way you've written your command, suggests you want the CONFIG_GREEN line commented out (making language assumptions), but your example output doesn't. Which do you want?

Comment: @vincent I did pull the sed query out of a loop in my script. What is odd is even with the loop constrained to just one file (normally multiple files) it still gives me the same behavior.

I want the CONFIG_GREEN commented out. I am testing a script to make bulk changes to a Linux kernel config.

Comment: Are you running the command multiple times on the same file? `-i` modifies the file in place.

Comment: @vincent No.... At least not on purpose. I will post the loop snippet. But the same loop is used multiple times and doesn't do this, that's what is odd.

Comment: Assuming you don't have any symlinks, which might cause the command to run multiple time on the same file, I cannot reproduce this. Also your example command will not create your example output.

Comment: @vincent I found the issue, you were right about the line already existing. I had removed the line with vim but for some reason, the line is still in the file. I wiped out the file 100% and now it works.

Comment: If you have ansible installed you should be able to handle this easily with the lineinfile module. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using GNU `sed`, your loop will append the line with a line saying `# CONFIG_GREEN=y` after each match of the regular expression `CONFIG_BLUE` in the file `test.txt`.  It will add the same line repeatedly in that same file for each filename in the current directory matching the shell globbing pattern `test*.txt`.

To get two lines of added text in `test.txt`, then either

1. there exists one other file with a filename matching `test*.txt` in the current directory, or
2. the line of text is already present in the file even before you run your loop, possibly from a previous run, or
3. you are not running the code that you think you are running.

Judging from [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671483/using-sed-to-match-and-add-new-line-to-config-file-produces-duplicate-line#comment1266527_671483), it was the second of these three cases.

To complete the modifications on the loop, use the loop variable in the actual call to `sed`.

```bsh
for name in test*.txt; do
  sed -e '/CONFIG_BLUE/a\' -e '# CONFIG_GREEN=y' "$name"
done
```

For now, I've removed the `-i` option to GNU `sed` to allow you to inspect the result and re-run without modifying any files.  Note that if you have a reasonable number of files, you would be able to call `sed` with the filename globbing pattern directly to operate on all files one after the other.  You would be able to use `-i` to do in-place editing here, too, provided that you are using GNU `sed`.

```bsh
sed -i -e '/CONFIG_BLUE/a\' -e '# CONFIG_GREEN=y' test*.txt
```